# DB2 + JPA throwing an error: column not found in the table

Tags: db2, jpa-2.0

The DB2-express is throwing an error that seems impossible, when JPA tries to persist an entity:

```
ReportingSQLException: "ITEMID" is not valid in the context where it is used..

INSERT INTO NULLID."DynamicDatabaseTable" ("colname", "rownumber", "value")
VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=?, ?, ?]
```

**Since ITEMID is not used in the query above, how can this error be?** The ITEMID is an auto-identity-generated column.

I have tried executing manually the query and it works OK, **so anybody know what's all about?** Even after lot of googling, I'm totally clueless here.

---

The database table in DB2 is fine, I have triple check:

```
"itemid" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1...), 
"rownumber" BIGINT NOT NULL, 
"colname" CHAR(30 OCTETS) NOT NULL, 
"value" VARCHAR(254 OCTETS)
```

---

I had created a simple java "JPA Entity from a table", by using the Eclipse wizard, and I've triple check the class is fine.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="\"itemid\"", unique=true, nullable=false)
private long itemid;

@Column(name="\"rownumber\"", nullable=false)
private long rownumber;

@Column(name="\"colname\"", nullable=false, length=30)
private String colname;

@Column(name="\"value\"", length=254)
private String value;
```

I have also restarted the whole computer just in case, but nothing... And I'm using most recent versions, clean installed couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"itemid"` is not equal `itemid` -- SQL identifiers are by default converted to upper case *if not enclosed in double quotation marks*. According to your DDL you created the table with lowercase column names. Apparently, JPA does not handle that properly and somewhere in the generated code uses unquoted `itemid`, which gets converted to upper case and, not surprisingly, the column cannot be found in the table.

There is no reason to use case sensitive identifiers in SQL, so I suggest you don't do that to avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: Re-created the table with uppercases _ITEMID_ and also re-created the entity with _insertable=false_ and it worked fine! It seems the ID field is somehow rescued from the DB to fill-in the java field.