# Query fails on Bluemix dashDB when the columns names are camel cased or lower cased

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have a Bluemix dashDB entry level instance. I have created a table which is as seen below

[image]

When i run the following query

```
select * from USERS where userId=2;
```

I get the following error

```
"USERID" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.69.56
```

The column does exist in my table. Am i missing out something here?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but similar. It helped me solve my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by following the post here [DB2 + JPA throwing an error: column not found in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172741/db2-jpa-throwing-an-error-column-not-found-in-the-table).

If the column names provided in the query should be matched exactly as in the table providing them within quotes works as expected.

By default the column names provided in the query are converted to uppercase.